# C++ Value of index in an array increment equivalent in Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c

I've below C++ codes and I've written as same of this C++ code into Objective C. But, `cnt[d[i]]++;` seems to be wrong in Objective-C.

Consider,

```
d[0] = 4
cnt[4] = 2
```

So, What is the exact meaning of `cnt[d[i]]++;` by using above values?

How can I solve this in Objective-C?

Example,

Here, What I am doing

**C++**

```
    int cnt[100001];
    int N = 4;
    int ans = 0;
    vector<int > d;
    d.resize(1000);
    int N = 4;
    for(int i = 0;  i < N; i++){

       cnt[d[i]]++;
       if(ans < cnt[d[i]])
       ans = cnt[d[i]];
    }
```

**Objective C**

```
int cnt[100001];
int ans = 0;
int i;
int N = 4;
NSMutableArray *d = [NSMutableArray new];
for(i = 0;  i < N; i++){
  int dOfI = [[d objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
  cnt[dOfI]++;
  if(ans < cnt[dOfI])
  ans = cnt[dOfI];
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Why 100001? Trying to hide an off by one error?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but regardless could you add where you declare `N` in both the C++ and Objective-C code excerpts?

Comment: *What is the exact meaning of cnt[d[i]]++* -- What is not understood by that code?  `d[i]` is a value, and whatever that value is, `cnt[value]` is incremented.

Comment: @user4581301, Question updated. Futher codes are not case sensitive. Only I can't understand `cnt[d[i]]++;` equivalent in Objective c

Comment: @AProgram -- There is nothing strange about that syntax.  How about if it was broken up?  `int value = d[i]; cnt[value]++;`, etc.?  It means the same thing.